# Debugging an error in my zsh startup script

Tags: zsh

My zsh terminals begin with an error code, as in `echo $?` is `1`. This hasn't actually caused any issues, but it's just annoying me. I would have thought that the commands from my various start up scripts would be included in `history`, but they are not; `history` seems to only show user-inputted commands.

What is a good process for debugging this situation?

Comment: What is the last command in your startup script?

Comment: Just run `zsh -x`

Comment: @waltinator it conditionally runs another zshrc file if that file exists:

```
if [[ -a $PATH ]]; then
  source #PATH
fi
```

In this case, that file does NOT exist. Furthermore, if I just `source ~/.zshrc` I get a 0 exit code.

Comment: Use `true`, a program that successfully does nothing, as the last line of the file.

Comment: @waltinator it's a good idea, but it didn't work. Again, `source`-ing my profile does NOT result in an error. That's why I'm trying to figure out what the hell else could be running at terminal start, aside from my profile

Comment: Unless you force the status (`$?`, `$STATUS`) with `true`, your script exits with the status of the last command executed. Also, `$PATH`  is a colon-separated list of directories, so `source $PATH` is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what your startup scripts do, or any other shell script, put `set -x` at the beginning, or before the part you want to understand. This causes the shell to trace every command it runs, i.e. print every command to standard error before executing it. To turn tracing off (in case you only want to trace part of your script — probably not useful for you), run `set -x`.

You can also start zsh in tracing mode by running `zsh -x`. (This might not reproduce the problem in your specific case, if the problem turns out to only happen when zsh is run directly by the terminal emulator, e.g. if you're relying on an environment variable before setting it.)

`set -x` prints traces on standard error. You can redirect this to a file by running `zsh -x 2>zsh.log`, or temporarily with

```
exec 2>zsh.log; set -x
… # stuff you want to trace
set +x; exec 2>/dev/tty
```

This causes standard error to not be a terminal, which might break some plugins. If it does, run `script -c 'zsh -x'` instead. This logs everything to a file called `typescript`, but still has zsh connected to a terminal.

---

> > Use true, a program that successfully does nothing, as the last line of the file. – waltinator
>
> @waltinator it's a good idea, but it didn't work.

Maybe a stray `return` outside of a function?

Comment: Maybe there's some way to set an environment variable in the graphical environment such that the terminal emulator will start zsh with -x already set?  Just from reading the question and the reply comments, the possibility you put in parentheses is the first idea that jumped to mind.  It sounds like something specific to either a login shell (if that's still relevant in zsh like it is in bash), or specific to how the terminal emulator starts up the shell.

Comment: @Wildcard It's possible, but it depends completely on the terminal emulator, which is not specified.